# Install PHP extension from code on Ubuntu, no makefile

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am trying to install this PHP extension:

https://github.com/kajidai/php-libmemcached

There is no makefile. There are a .c, .h, .xml and .mp4 files.

How can I install it on Ubuntu?

Comment: Whats wrong with the package manager?

Comment: `apt-get install php5-memcached memcached`.

Comment: Stony, I don't think this PHP extension is available in Ubuntu Repositories (if I understand your question correctly). It is not the same as php-memcached. I need to use this version because I am trying to migrate a PHP app from Centos system to Ubuntu, and the Centos System is using this extension.

Comment: Your `.mp4` file is actually an `.m4` file for automake. Typically you will want to use `phpize` however to get a configure and then make script.

Comment: Mario, I am not familiar with either aotomake or phpize. Is it easy to use?

Comment: phpize it is! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason for building it from the source ?

What about doing it in a simpler way as mentioned here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-use-memcache-on-ubuntu-12-04

To install it from source you have to do something like this:

```
cd memcached/
phpize
./configure && make
sudo make install
```

Note: if **phpize** command is not working then installation is needed( apt-get install php5-dev).

Comment: The question is about installing the PHP extension, which doesn't have a `configure` script.

Comment: I need to build it from source because this version is not available in package repos

Comment: @duskwuff : sorry i missed that. Updating answer..

Comment: phpize created configure and makefile for me. Thank you very much